# How do I combine JSF Ajax with Bookmark-able views?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a **p:dataTable** and a number of controls to it that change its content such as page number, sort, and filter parameters.  The controls invoke AJAX interaction so that each change invokes a SQL query to the back end, but updates just the table in the client browser.  That's the way it is supposed to be, right?

What I can't figure out is the best practice for making the view bookmark-able. It is easy enough to get the bookmark parameters into the backing bean such as:

```
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="orderNo" value="#{bean.orderNo}" />
            <f:viewParam name="sortOrder" value="#{bean.sortOrder}" />
            <f:viewParam name="showOpenItems" value="#{bean.showOpenItems}" />           
            <f:viewParam name="page" value="#{bean.page}" />
            <f:viewParam name="pageSize" vlaue="#{bean.pageSize}" />
        </f:metadata>
```

So say I add a radioButton control to change the sortOrder.  It might look like this:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.sortOrder}">
   <p:ajax update="@form" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="xxx" itemValue="1" />
      (etc)
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

First question:  When this AJAX enabled control is fired is there any way to preserve the OTHER parameters such as **orderNo** without resorting to a ViewScoped bean?

Second question: How do I get the browser's URL bar to update so that if the user bookmarks the page, all the current table query parameters are preserved?

Much thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the parameters to any component using `<f:param>` and reading it from your request scoped backing bean. You can use OmniFaces `Components.getParams(UIComponent)` function.

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.sortOrder}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.reload()}" update="@form" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="xxx" itemValue="1" />

    <f:param name="orderNo" value="#{bean.orderNo}"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Retrieve params from component in request bean:

```
public void reload()
{
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context);

    List<ParamHolder> params = Components.getParams(component);

    // extract orderNo param and reload your datasource
}
```

To update your browser URL you can either perform GET-requests instead of ajax or you can manipulate it using javascript history API.

For first part you can use this utility request bean function in your ajax or command components.

```
/**
 * Redirects to the given outcome by building a bookmarkable URL using all
 * child UIParameter's of the current component.
 *
 * @param outcome
 * @param includeViewParam
 *
 * @return
 */
public void performActionParams(final String outcome, boolean includeViewParam)
{
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context);

    List<ParamHolder> params = Components.getParams(component);

    String url = FacesLocal.getBookmarkableURL(context, outcome, params, includeViewParam);
    FacesContextUtils.redirect(context, url);
}
```